# Inserting an iframe to a specific location on top of a png

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a png:
[image]

I need to insert the iframe into the laptop screen.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please come back when you have tried something and can provide a relevant code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Define some div and place laptop image as a background image.
2. Place iframe within div and apply position:absolute with some margins and dimensions

Here is snippet (feel free to play with dimensions-positions...):

```css
#laptop {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/plSBJ.png);
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 63px;
    width: 286px;
    height: 178px;
}
```

```html
<div id="laptop">
    <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050297/inserting-an-iframe-to-a-specific-location-on-top-of-a-png">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not adaptive for different resolutions

Comment: @DanilKalinin I don't see that specified as a requirement in your question.

Comment: @DanilKalinin Instead of px, you can use percentage...